# How to insert my association id into simple form for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, simple-form-for

I have an model that belongs to different models (game belongs to field and organiser), but when I fill the form to create the game, my creation method is not catching up the field reference

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :organiser
 belongs_to :field
end

class Organiser < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
end

class Field < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Controller

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def new
  @organiser = Organiser.find(params[:organiser_id])
  @game = Game.new
 end

 def create
  @game = Game.new(game_params)
  organiser_id = current_organiser.id
  @organiser = Organiser.find(organiser_id)
  @game.organiser = @organiser
  @game.save
  redirect_to organiser_games_path(@organiser)
 end

 def edit
  organiser_id = current_organiser.id
  @organiser = Organiser.find(params[:organiser_id])
 end

 def update
  organiser_id = current_organiser.id
  @organiser = Organiser.find(organiser_id)
  @game.update(game_params)
  redirect_to organiser_games_path(@organiser)
end

private
def game_params
 params.require(:game).permit(:field_id, :total_players)
end

def set_game
 @game = Game.find(params[:id])
end
```

_form parcel for new and edit view

```
<%= simple_form_for [@organiser, @game] do |f| %>
 <div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :field_id, as: :select, collection: Field.all.collect(&:location) %>
  <%= f.input :total_players %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

I am a beginner, and if you guys can help me with basic solutions that will help me to understand the complex bit, I will appreciate

I received no message, it looked like it went trough but it did not

Comment: Use `association` for `field`. Checkout https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

Answer (score 1):

`collection: Field.all.collect(&:location)`

Your collection has to be an array with the relation's id and the displayed value. Here, you only collect the value of `location` for each Field.

this code should do the trick:

```
<%= f.input :field_id, as: :select, collection: Field.all.map { |field| [field.id, field.location] } %>
```

`field.id` will be the value of your select option (currently, there's no value so it can't works), and `field.location` will be the text of your select option. :)